# not inputting values into array, even though its going into the if loop

Tags: java

I have a method called displayWord that is supposed to compare each index of an array with another array and if the indexes match, it is supposed to execute this line  `displayedWord[i] = wordArray[i]`. When I print the displayedWord, they are all question marks even thought the print statement executes so I know it is going into the if block.

Why is displayedWord always questions marks when I print it?

```
public static void displayWord(char[] correctGuesses, char[] wordArray) {
        char[] displayedWord = new char[wordArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < correctGuesses.length; j++) {
                if(wordArray[i] == correctGuesses[j]) {
                    displayedWord[i] = wordArray[i];
                    System.out.println("they are the same");
                } else displayedWord[i] = '?';
            }
        }
        for(char c : displayedWord) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a `break;` inside the `if` block (after `System.out.println("they are the same");`)

Comment: That ended up in weird behavior as the overall programs prompts the user again after executing this method.

Comment: Do `correctGuesses` and `wordArray` have the same length?

Comment: Are you intentionally comparing each element of `wordArray` with every element of `correctGuesses`, rather than just the element with the same index? Step through your program with the debugger.

Comment: They are the same length and I am intentionally comparing each element of wordArray with every element in correctGuesses. About to step through with debugger.

Comment: Thanks, then imagine what happens if wordArray = "aa" and correctGuesses = "ab", or better, run the debugger and see what happens. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Break actually fixed it. Coincidentally when I added break the first time, my IDE bugged out resulting in the weird behavior I mentioned and needed a restart.

Answer (score 3):

#### That's because you are overeating the displayedWord, even if the char was found

Use break when you find the char to get out of the loop

### here is the code

```
public static void displayWord(char[] correctGuesses, char[] wordArray) {
    char[] displayedWord = new char[wordArray.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < correctGuesses.length; j++) {
            if(wordArray[i] == correctGuesses[j]) {
                displayedWord[i] = wordArray[i];
                System.out.println("they are the same");
                break;
            } else displayedWord[i] = '?';
        }
    }
    for(char c : displayedWord) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not comparing the corresponding indices of the two arrays, because you have defined a double for loop with two different variables.
With your code above it loops through each element of wordArray and compares every element of correctGuesses array for each wordArray element.

To get what you want, you only want to have one for loop which iterates n-times where n is the length of the smaller array.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the correct character at the next iteration when your code hits the `else` case.

And it also seems like you don't need a nested loop to check whether a character in the array of guesses a matches a character in the containing correct characters (in case if characters at the same position need to be compared).

```
public static void displayWord(char[] correctGuesses, char[] wordArray) {
    int len = Math.min(correctGuesses.length, wordArray.length);
    char[] displayedWord = new char[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(wordArray[i] == correctGuesses[i]) {
            displayedWord[i] = wordArray[i];
            System.out.println("they are the same " + wordArray[i]);
        } else displayedWord[i] = '?';
    }
    
    for(char c : displayedWord) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayWord(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'},new char[]{'e', 'b', 'e'});
}
```

*Output:*

```
they are the same b
?b?
```

Comment: I could be wrong but doesnt this compare only the same indexed element in correctGuesses rather than every element in correctGuesses?

Comment: @guts716 You need to find a matching character at same position in both array `wordArray` and  `correctGuesses`? If the answer is yes, then you need only one loop.

Comment: @guts716 If a matching character in the `wordArray` can be located at any position, that means that the same character `wordArray` can match multiple characters in the `correctGuesses` array (i.e. a single `a` in {'a', 'b', 'c'} would match two characters in the {'a', 'u', 'a'})

Comment: @guts716 Which of these was your original intention? The first option is represented in the example in my answer.